# How do I properly set the request header of a Rhomobile API call?

Tags: api, get, rhomobile

Environment:

Windows Server 2012 Standard 
rhodes-3.5.1.13 - MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13 
jQuery Mobile 1.6.4 
Java jdk1.6.0_24

Description: 
After making this call..

```
    Rho::AsyncHttp.get( 
    :url => url, 
    :headers => { 
    'Accept'=>'application/json', 
    'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,sdch', 
    'Accept-Language'=>'en-US,en;q=0.8' 
    }, 
    :callback => callback, 
    :callback_param => callback_param 
    )
```

...the result of this request returns the following:

```
    "Rho::AsyncHttp....callback_param)" {"rho_callback"=>"1", "status"=>"error", "error_code"=>"1", "headers"=>{"Accept"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch", "Accept-Language"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8", "User-Agent"=>"Mozilla-5.0 (ANDROID; Win32; 4.0.3)"}, "body"=>""}
```

Question: 
Is there a Rhomobile limitation on the headers that I am allowed to pass to this call? It seems to work if I paste the url, with the headers, into Fiddler. When I remove 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,sdch', the response is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes uses libcURL for implementing the AsyncHTTP API in v3.5 of the framework as is possible to see in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/3-5-stable/platform/shared/net/CURLNetRequest.cpp).

So whatever is possible to do in libcURL, the same is possible to do in ASyncHTTP.

In your particular case I'll probably use the "Content-Type" instead of the "Accept" header:

```
 Rho::AsyncHttp.get( 
    :url => url, 
    :headers => { 
    'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 
    'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,sdch', 
    'Accept-Language'=>'en-US,en;q=0.8' 
    }, 
    :callback => callback, 
    :callback_param => callback_param 
    )
```

If you want to test this in Rhodes v4.0, there now the Network API that you can use in the same way:

```
getProps = Hash.new
getProps['url'] = url
getProps['headers'] = {"Content-Type" => "application/json",
                       "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch", 
                       "Accept-Language"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8"}
Rho::Network.get(getProps, url_for(:action => :callback))
```